# How to convert a HEIF/HEIC image to JPEG in macOS?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos.app, file-conversion, image-editing

So, here’s the thing. I have a new iPhone and an old Mac. iOS 11 (still in beta as of today) and El Capitan (no more updates for this Mac). I use iCloud photo library in both devices. When I take a photo in the new format with my iPhone 7, is there any way to use it right away in my mac, without having to convert it in my iPhone first? I mean, can I get those photos synced through iCloud and converted locally on my Mac?

I have tried to find a third party software that could do that kind of conversion, but was not able to find any that would work on El Capitan. Any idea?

Comment: You should be able to convert HEIF photos on export.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I am still trying to understand the mechanics of it. I have set it to Automatic in the iPhone. But I got a couple heic files in Photos app through iCloud Photo Library sync and also when downloading from iCloud website. I guess the website shout allow us to export a JPEG. And it would be nice to have the same in Photos app, in El Capitan.

Comment: I would like to start using the new format in order to save space, but still have some way to access my photos from my current Mac.

Comment: Well... Now I was able to download a JPG version of a HEIC photo from iCloud website. Not sure if I changed something in my settings since the last time I tried. But  Photos app still reports the synced file (not the one I downloaded) as a .HEIC. And if I try to export it, it  does not work. Only JPGs get exported. Which is weird, because the photo gets displayed normally in the  photos app.

Comment: There is an app called Graphic Converter but it doesn't support these formats. You might want to keep an eye on it.<https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/key-features/import-and-export-formats/>

Comment: @Mark yeah, that was one of my first thoughts, but it seems that their HEIC conversion is a feature that only works in a more recent OS.

Comment: Have you tried Image Capture?

Comment: @IconDaemon I don’t think Image Capture can convert file types. It certainly cannot open image files already in the computer file system. Remember, my photo files are already stored in the computer, because I am using iCloud Photo Library. Also, I am using “Optimized Storage” in both devices, so the actual original image file is usually in iCloud server, not necessarily in one of my devices.

Comment: Strangely enough, i have now a few HEIC photos in my library, and when I try to download them from iCloud website, at least one of them comes out as a JPG, but most are downloaded as HEIC. I tryed that in at least three different Macs with El Capitan. What's the criteria for the server to decide if it will send us a JPG or a HEIC file?

Comment: The only way I was able to get a partial sollution for this problem, until now,  was going to iCloud website, Photos, then select one of the photos and click the share link at the top (the square thing with an arrow pointing up). Then choose "email". It opens a popup window with the photo inside. At that time, you may drag that photo to your Desktop, and you'll get a JPG. It's not full resolution, but probably will do for web and other purposes that do not require a full-res image.

Comment: Now, another very strange issue is that the share button in the Photos web-app, in iCloud website, does not show up in every computer, even if all of them are using El Capitan... Shouldn't a feature like this the hardware independent?

Comment: @IconDaemon When importing photos with a cable, with Photos app or Image Capture, the HEIC photos show up and are imported as JPG files (I have set it to Automatic, in iPhone's preferences). It can be a workaround for recent photos, but still not a solution for photos that came through iCloud sync and that may not be locally available in iPhone anymore...

Comment: `sips -s format JPEG myfile.heic --out myfile.jpg`

Comment: And the multiple file version: `for i in *.HEIC; do sips -s format JPEG "${i}" --out "${i%HEIC}JPG"; done`  (from https://robservatory.com/use-sips-to-quickly-easily-and-freely-convert-image-files/)

Comment: `sips` on El Capitan does not work for converting HEIC images.

Comment: @PatNiemeyer and @dmon that should be `sips -s format jpeg` with lowercase `jpeg`. Uppercase gives `Error: Unsupported output format JPEG` (sips-294 on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5)

Comment: Try jpeg (lowercase) instead of JPEG (uppercased) in the sips command. Worked like that for me on macOS ventura.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We just released this **little free app** for macOS:
https://imazing.com/heic

Minimum macOS version is **10.8**, so no worries with El Capitan. : )

[image]

Comment: This tool also preserves EXIF data too, which is awesome!

Comment: Not working recently

Answer (score 164):

You can use the command line tool `imagemagick` to convert HEIC images to JPG.

```bash
# install imagemagick
brew install imagemagick

# convert a single image
magick convert foo.HEIC foo.jpg

# bulk convert multiple images
magick mogrify -monitor -format jpg *.HEIC
```

Update: Now MacOS provides a [built-in converter using Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297134/how-to-convert-a-heif-heic-image-to-jpeg-in-macos/439767#439767), if you want a GUI solution.

Comment: What does "convert: no decode delegate for this image format `HEIC" mean?

Comment: @gap, you error message means you don't have the right stuff installed to deal with the HEIC format. `brew upgrade imagemagick` solved this problem for me.

Comment: @gap Not sure. My original install command had an extra option: `brew install imagemagick --with-libheif`, but others said it wasn't needed anymore. You could give that a try. Maybe it makes a difference depending on your OSX version.

Comment: @wisbucky, regarding my non-deleted answer: you were right. not sure what was going on before. Thanks for the feedback. 

Comment: Perfect! worked for me

Comment: You need `libde265` to use HEIC with ImageMagick... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558699/2836621

Answer (score 82):

The macOS-native way of doing image conversions like these is apparently `sips(1)` (raising comments of [Pat Niemeyer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/173729/pat-niemeyer) and [jonatan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/173316/jonatan) to proper answer status, for improved findability):

```sh
sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions best myfile.heic --out myfile.jpg
```

So if you have a directory full of HEIC files, you can launch a macOS Big Sur terminal, where, if you run the default Zsh shell, you can make jpeg copies of all those files like this:

```sh
for i in *.heic(:r); do sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions best "$i.heic" --out "$i.jpg"; done;
```

…and presto, you've got jpeg copies!

If you want to also nuke the originals, follow up with a `rm *.heic` –
or use this variant instead:

```shell
for i in *.heic(:r); do sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions best "$i.heic" --out "$i.jpg" && rm "$1.heic"; done;
```

…and integrating Josh Hibschman's tip to also retain timestamps:

```sh
find . -type f -iname '*.heic' | while read i; do \
  fileNoExt="${i%.*}"; \
  jpgFile="${fileNoExt}_heic_conv.jpg"; \
  sips -s format jpeg -s formatOptions best "$i" --out "$jpgFile"; \
  touch -r "$i" "$jpgFile"; \
  rm "$i"; \
done
```

Comment: Without question this should be the definitive answer. No extra software to be installed, as simple as it can get.

Comment: When I try this in `bash` I get `Warning: .heic not a valid file - skipping`. The `imagemagick` solution works for me.

Comment: What does the `(:r)` qualifier do?

Comment: `(:r)` is a zsh globbing filename generation feature that removes a filename extension from matches, so `*.heic(:r)` would match example files `a.heic` and `b.heic` as `a b`.

Comment: Recommend adding `touch -r myfile.heic myfile.jpg` to copy over created and modified dates.. or altogether with renaming `find . -type f -iname '*.HEIC' | while read i
do
  fileNoExt="${i%.*}"; 
  jpgFile="${fileNoExt}_heic_conv.JPG";
  sips -s format jpeg "$i" --out "$jpgFile";
  touch -r "$i" "$jpgFile";
  rm "$i";
done
`

Comment: How could we match *.heic and *.HEIC files in the for loop?

Comment: Using the last command (`find ...`) I got a "parse error near done". I had to add a semicon after "read i" so the first line reads `find . -type f -iname '*.heic' | while read i; do`

Comment: That `while` loop had a syntax error on `done` I used  (crap SO markdown apparently has no multiline code formatting, so good luck reading this)

`for f in $(ls *.HEIC)
do
  fileNoExt="${f%.*}"
  jpgFile="${fileNoExt}.jpg"
  sips -s format jpeg "$f" --out "$jpgFile"
  touch -r "$f" "$jpgFile"
done`

Comment: The bash syntax for the "for loop" is: `for i in *.HEIC ; do sips -s format jpeg "$i" --out "$i.jpg"; done`. Although the output filename pattern will be `foo.HEIC.jpg`

Comment: I ended up making a terminal command via making an alias in my .zshrc (or .bashrc): `alias heic2jpg='for i in *.HEIC(:r); do sips -s format jpeg "$i.heic" --out "$i.jpg" && touch -r "$i.HEIC" "$i.jpg"; done;'`. Then I can just `cd` into the directory with all my HEIC and run `heic2jpg`

Answer (score 24):

Use the built-in "Convert Image" macOS Quick Action to easily convert HEIC images to JPEG.

[image: Convert Image Quick Action]

the right-click menu item opens up a small utility for converting to various formats and sizes:

[image: Convert Image]

Comment: this is elegant!

Comment: Hmm I did that and it worked. But the image is in low quality, even though I selected "actual size". Furthermore: Now when I copy any other image from the Photos App to a new folder in Finder, its automatically in "low" quality and in ".jpeg" format instead of ".heic".

Do you know how to revert this?

Answer (score 8):

I found [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/photos-videos/ios-formats) to be a good conversion tool, as it does it transparently for the usage on any operating system and platform.

When you do the shot from iPhone, Dropbox automatically converts `.heic` image to `.jpg` when uploading it to computer ([controlled by the settings](https://www.dropbox.com/help/photos-videos/ios-formats)). Since I'm using both Windows OS and MacOS, there's no need to install separate additional applications.

Answer (score 3):

Below an online (web browser) conversion tool: doesn’t support batch processing but it will work on a wide range of systems, including non-Apple OSs.

http://heictojpg.com/

Comment: This website now lets you upload up to 50 images at once.

Comment: Keep in mind: you are uploading your pics to a third-party cloud service (and you have no guarantee they will delete them afterward). Do not use it for personal stuff,

Answer (score 3):

my two cents for Catalina.

I was tired of using cmd line...

I wrote a small app... if interested. it's free:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/heictojpeg/id1486256731?ls=1&mt=12

hope can be useful
:)

Comment: and now is AppleSilicon-ready

Answer (score 2):

An excellent command line tool that works very well is [tifig](https://github.com/monostream/tifig). It can be easily compiled on multiple platforms. It should compile on any platform with a relatively modern development toolchain, that should include El Capitan!

Comment: I followed the instructions in the repo to install `tifig` using `brew install cmake vips ffmpeg` (from the repo) but it doesn't seem to work (`tifig command not found`).

Comment: I don't know if you did or not, but you have to follow the build instructions as well. To execute inside build folder after build, just run `./tifig -v -p file.heic file.jpg`

Comment: Could a demo brew install and usage be provided to turn this into a more complete answer? As it stands it's more of a comment.