# Copy/Paste image from Photos to Messages converts HEIC to JPEG and loses resolution on macOS

Tags: icloud, photos, messages, copy-paste, heic

I want to send images from macOS Photos in an iMessage conversation.

When I **copy/paste** an image from macOS Photos to iMessage, it is converted to a JPEG file and downsampled. This loses the Live Photo video and results in a much lower resolution image.

---

Original image from iCloud Photos Library on macOS:

> `.HEIC`, Live Photo, `4032x3024`, 1.1 MB

[image: image in Photos]

---

After copy/paste to Messages and send:

> `.jpeg`, not Live Photo, `1024x769`, 218 KB, creation and modification dates have been changed to today.

[image: image after copy/pasted and sent in Messages]

---

If I instead **drag** the photo to the Message conversation, rather than copy/paste, it is properly sent:

> `.HEIC`, Live Photo, `4032x3024`, 1.1 MB, filename has been changed.

[image: dragged file]

---

Why is copy/paste not transmitting the full resolution file?

Is there a setting that controls the quality of copy/pasted images from Photos or into Messages?

Comment: Hey pkamb, I have the same issue. This only happened to me after trying to convert .heic images to .jpg using this "quick action" method. Now whenever I copy an Image from the photos app to a new folder in finder, the image is saved as .jpeg in low quality instead of .heic

Have you found a solution for this problem?

This only happened to my after playing around with this "quick action" https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439767/285241

Comment: Interestingly, sometimes when I copy and paste a HEIF from photos, it comes out as a HEIF, and other times it comes out as a JPEG. I can't find any clear pattern to help me figure out when it does which. I just did two HEIFs in a row; one pasted as a HEIF (into an application that doesn't accept those); the other pasted as a JPEF (which worked fine).